Why trade credit is considered as an investment
One of the Foreign Direct Investment (FDI) components is debt. I understand that a loan given from a foreign investor to an affiliate company in another country is a form of investment as there will be an income from this loan in the form of interest. But I don't understand how trade credit from a direct investor to its affiliate in another country is considered as an investment when there is no interest or other form of income resulting from this trade credit. Thank you for your explanation.

I believe in its definition of FDI the OECD does not consider whether an instrument earns income or not.

Yes they did not consider that, they only talked about having a long lasting interest in the foreign enterprise, but I thought that economically by definition an investment should be done to earn income.
